# How can i only show date and month select box in calender(Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, widget, date, datepicker, calendar

I want my customer edit form calendar to be only date and month and no year and no week days name.
This must include leap year as well if a `user` birthday is on 29th Feb and according to this current calendar which has the `the year 2019`, it wont show 29th Feb.

So, I want a calendar widget to only show all `month` and `day` (leap + non-leap)

Comment: still not resolve? :) try this `<script>
        require([
            'jquery',
            'jquery/ui'
        ], function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
               $("#ui-datepicker-div").datepicker({
         dateFormat: 'MM dd'
            });
            });
        });
    </script> `

Comment: that one worked for me

Comment: @magefms it worked last time, just ran into this issue